# VBA - Stop program from quitting, minimize instead

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to write a macro for Outlook that is called when I click the X.  I want the Application_Quit() subroutine to stop the program from quitting, then minimize it instead.  I can figure out the minimization, but how to I prevent it from quitting?

Comment: I know of some programs that do that, but it is always an option that the user has to turn on.  I wouldn't want that to be a macro in Outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not truly possible to prevent the close. You can tell based on the method signature of the Application_Quit() event:

```
   Private Sub Application_Quit()

   End Sub
```

A cancellable event will look like this:

```
   Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

   End Sub
```

I searched around, and found a kind of cool hacky trick, though, if you don't mind the side-effect that Outlook automatically minimizes when it launches (found on [this forum](http://www.techsupportforum.com/microsoft-support/microsoft-office-support/43048-cant-minimize-outlook-2003-startup-tried-everything.html), copied and reformatted):

Trick is to add a macro that auto-minimizes Outlook when it starts:

> Hit Alt-F11 to go to the VBA editor.
>   Paste this sub in the
>   "ThisOutlookSession" section:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    SendKeys ("% n") 
End Sub
```

> Now after Outlook loads it will
>   minimize. I also use this next one to
>   minimize instead of close when someone
>   attempts to close outlook.

```
Private Sub Application_Quit() 
     Call Shell("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\relaunchOL.bat" _
       , vbHide)
End Sub
```

> Create C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\OFFICE11\relaunchOL.bat and put
>   these two lines in it:

```
Ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\outlook.exe"
```

> This will give Outlook a couple of
>   seconds to close, then relaunch
>   itself, then minimize itself sinse you
>   have the macro for minimize in
>   startup.

Comment: HI BradC just one thing I want to confirm from you what is 1.2.3.4 in the ping command, is this the IP address of your machine?? Plz confirm

Comment: @deepesh: I'd assume that's in the batch file only for the delay for the ping to complete. No, it doesn't have to be a real IP address, in fact, its better if it is not a real IP, because it takes longer trying to resolve it than it would if it were real (~20 seconds vs ~5 seconds).